# ELK Dashboard showing wrong data/results

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm new to ELK Stack and trying to setup a dashboard to analyze my apache access logs. Setting up the environment and displaying data from my logfiles all worked. But it seems like Kibana is mistakenly using spaces (and in another dashboard colons and minuses) as separators.

The first two screenshots show that the information inside my attribute "server_node" are correct.

[image: Parsed date in Kibana]
[image: Parsed date in logstash console-output]

Sadly this one shows that every space-sign is used as separator. So instead of "Tomcat Website Prod 1" or "Tomcat Website Prod 2" as seen in server_node there are too many entries and thus falsify my graph.

[image: Parsed date in Kibana]

This is my widget setting. As mentioned I'm new to ELK and hence don't have that much knowledge to set up good dashbards.
[image: Widget Settings]

Does anyone of you have any expirience with setting up kibana to analyze apache access logs and can give me a hint on how to setup expressive dashboards or can give me a sample dashboard to use as a model?

Thanks for your help and time and regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem you are running into is that strings are `analyzed` by default -- which is what you want in a text search engine, but not what you want in an analytics type of situation.  You need to set the field to `not_analyzed` before loading it in.

If you are using logstash 1.3.1 or later to load your data, you should be able to change your field to `server_node.raw` (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/logstash-1-3-1-released/):

> Most folks, in this situation, sit and scratch their heads, right? I know I did the first time. I’m pretty certain “docs” and “centralized” aren’t valid paths on the logstash.net website! The problem here is that the pie chart is built from a terms facet. With the default text analyzer in elasticsearch, a path like “/docs/1.3.1/filters/” becomes 3 terms {docs, 1.3.1, filters}, so when we ask for a terms facet, we only get individual terms back!
>
> Index templates to the rescue! The logstash index template we provide adds a “.raw” field to every field you index. These “.raw” fields are set by logstash as “not_analyzed” so that no analysis or tokenization takes place – our original value is used as-is! If we update our pie chart above to instead use the “request.raw” field, we get the following:

Comment: A complete answer should mention that it's possible to change how fields are indexed and that the analysis can be disabled for fields where it never makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Using the raw-field did the trick.